# FIM Syncronization Services fails to start - User Profile Synchronization won't start

Tags: 2013, user-profile-service, powershell, fim

User Profile Synchronization was working ok and after one restart FIM Synchronization Services fails to start and User Profile Synchronization won't start.

I have follow harbar.net article for setting up User Profile Synchronization
[Rational Guide to implementing SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups.aspx)

I read all Common Issues and didn't find answer for my case in this article
[Stuck on Starting: Common Issues with SharePoint Server 2010 User Profile Synchronization](http://www.harbar.net/articles/sp2010ups2.aspx)

**Stuck on Starting and ULS logs event 9i1w: ILM Configuration: Error ‘ERR_CONFIG_DB’**

This is due to insufficient privileges for the SharePoint Farm Account on the Sync DB (not the Config DB!). You need to add the farm account to the Sync DB users as DBO with a default schema of DBO and then start UPS again.

I had exactly the same eventID in ULS log (9i1w) with ILM Configuration: Error.
Farm account was already there in Sync DB users.

And i have this error.

*UserProfileApplication.SynchronizeMIIS: Failed to configure MIIS post database, will attempt during next rerun...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem for my case was profile.ps1 for PowerShell.

Answer is to comment all code (Admin rights, Add-PSSnapin etc.) in profile.ps1.

1. Open Windows PowerShell ISE like always (Run as Admin)
2. Run this `if (!(test-path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts)) {new-item -type file -path $profile.AllUsersAllHosts –force} powershell_ise $profile.AllUsersAllHosts`
3. if profile.ps1 isn't empty add "<#" before code, and after code add "#>" to comment all code
4. CTRL+S
5. Close Windows PowerShell ISE and open it again (now will start without profile.ps1 because it is commented)
6. Go to *Central Administration* (CA) > *Manage services on server* and Start *User Profile Synchronization Service*
7. Open [ULS Viewer 2014](http://blogs.technet.com/b/wbaer/archive/2014/08/22/uls-viewing-like-a-boss-uls-viewer-is-now-available.aspx), press CTRL+U and search for message ILM and 9i1w
8. Under *Manage services on server*, *User Profile Synchronization Service* will be "Started" after 3-4 minutes.